# ros2 difference between colcon test and launch_test

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are appropriate use cases for each one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377032/ros2-difference-between-colcon-test-and-launch_test/) by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`launch_test` is a command that is provided by the [`launch_testing` package](https://github.com/ros2/launch/tree/master/launch_testing). It can be used to run tests that are described/set up using a launch file, e.g.

```
$ launch_test path/to/my_launch_test.py
```

The test must be set up in a very specific way. The Python launch file must define a `generate_test_description()` function that returns a `LaunchDescription`. I don't think this file needs to be part of a package; it might be able to just be a standalone file. For example:

```
def generate_test_description():

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=[path_to_process],
        ),

        # Start tests right away - no need to wait for anything in this example.
        # In a more complicated launch description, we might want this action happen
        # once some process starts or once some other event happens
        launch_testing.actions.ReadyToTest()
    ])
```

See this README: https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/3a5c9df2e384271637ac029f48f020b7916498d6/launch_testing/README.md.

---

[`colcon test` is a command](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/test.html) that runs *all* tests for a given package (or given packages): C++ tests (e.g. [defined as a CMake test in a `CMakeLists.txt` using `ament_add_gtest(...)`](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html#testing)), or Python tests (e.g. defined as a CMake test in a `CMakeLists.txt` using `ament_add_pytest_test(...)` or just a Python file under a `test/` directory in a pure Python package). E.g.

```
$ colcon test --packages-select my_package
```

Some of those Python test files can be launch tests similar to the example above, but the `generate_test_description()` function has to be annotated with `@pytest.mark.launch_test` for the test file to be run properly. I think in this case the same file can also be run using `launch_test`.

---

In general, you can simply just use `colcon test` to run your tests.

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2021-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6